# Renaming multiple files at once with a pattern on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rename

I have around 300 files named

```
some_name_123456789.zip
another-name2_987654321.zip
something(1)_123454321.zip
[2]something_987656789.zip
```

I need to rename them all to

```
ds_123456789.zip
ds_987654321.zip
ds_123454321.zip
ds_987656789.zip
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with the `rename` command line utility. To do what you want you need a simple regular expression:

> `rename "s/.+_/ds/g"` *`files`*

`.+` represents everything up to (in this context) the last underscore (`_`) character (so this works with multiple underscores, as mentioned in your first example). This requires that there be at least one character before the underscore; if you might have file names like `_20131012.zip`, use `.*` instead. So this three-character string (`.+_` or `.*_`) will match everything up to *and including* the last underscore in the filename. `s/old/new/` means **s**ubstitute the new string (`ds`) for the old string. The `g` means **g**lobal and might not be necessary in this case.

Comment: To be sure that the regexp matches from the beginning I would rather put `^` to the beginning. Also OP wanted to retain the underscore. The `g` option at the end is not really needed here - it would match multiple instances in the file name if possible. So I think this command would perform better: `rename "s/^.+_/ds_/" files`

Comment: adding the `g` is just a standard habit from me and i agree that it's not needed in this case.

Comment: Does this work for a list of folders too or what do you add to make it?

Comment: Maybe i would use the find utilty the exec option, but this depends on the names of the files you are working on. To rename the zip files mentioned above you can use `find . -name "*.zip*" -exec rename "s/.+_/ds/g" {} \;` where "{} \;" is the variable for the filename find returns.

Answer (score 1):

or, using the cross-platform [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer):

```
$ renamer --regex --find '.+_' --replace 'ds' *
```